# Android Chrome shares only screenshot

Tags: android, google-chrome, share

I want to share the current url via Chrome on Android to my app. I have registered a share-intent and the share-filter. So far i get a shared screenshot, but not the url. What am i doing wrong?

manifest-file

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.share.ShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 7+ -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activity.main.MainActivity" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This is the code-snippet used in a method in the ShareActivity class

```
public URI shareUriFromIntent() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    if (type != null && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
        ClipData data = intent.getClipData();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getItemCount(); i++) {
            ClipData.Item item = data.getItemAt(i);

//breakpoint: output> ClipData { text/uri-list "" {U:content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1462970510861-711948848.jpg} }

                if (item.getText() != null) {
                    String shareText = item.getText().toString();
                    if (shareText.contains("http:/")
                            || shareText.contains("https:/")) {
                        shareText = shareText.substring(shareText.indexOf("http"));
                        return URI.create(shareText); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
    }
```

There is no url or uri, i would have used. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final String link = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

did the trick.